# Access table data when using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, web

Okay, I can post the PHP code if needed but I'm trying to use some data in my database, but have no idea how I can access it. It might be an easy reply but I'm new to this game...

Basically, I have been able to set up a login system for my site, where if you log in, it will display the logged in user's username, this is done through the use of $_SESSION and a session class.

Where if the user is logged in ($session->logged_in) etc

```
        <h3>Welcome <? echo $session->username?> </h3>
        </head>

                <body>
      <p> Welcome to the website, your details are below </p>

        </body>
        <?php } ?>
```

I return the user's username as such.

However, I can only currently access data from the table 'users', and 'users' is connected through foreign keys to a table called 'passengers' through the 'username' field.

What I would like to do, is instead of printing the username, print the user's surname.

So essentially it is like:-

Logging in sets up a session and recognises the username that is logged in.
By querying this username in a different table, can pull up data from all corresponding tables in the database.

But I have no idea how to go about it..

If you guys and girls know of any sample code, or could point me in the right direction that'd be fantastic.

Comment: Why can you only access data from the table 'users'? You should be able to use the same techniques you are using for that table to retrieve data from the 'passengers' table also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");

$query = "SELECT surname FROM passengers WHERE username = " . $session->username . "";
$result = mysql_query($query);  

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "Hello, your lastname is $data";
?>
```

I think this is what you are referring to?

Also, even though you're new at php etc., try looking into mysql injection and how to prevent it (this current code is very susceptible to mysql injection -- if it were to use user input; thanks to Carrie Kendall lol =])

Good place to start is by using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

edit-
Not sure but this might also help out as I'm not entirely sure what you mean; [mysql (left) join](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php)

Comment: Haha, yeah I guess you're right.. Still might be handy to refer to it anyways :D

Comment: I am using mySQL as the post refers to, thanks. That's great thank you. I shall try what you lot have suggested. A passing thought, if I want to access more than one field, for example the user's first name and surname. Would I just do this query for the number of fields I wanted to access? Or is there a way, where I could put for example the entire PASSENGER table into an array or what not, and then just call $surname etc.

Comment: Also @Bono, the code you suggested throws an error of
`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`...any ideas?

Many thanks for yours and @CarrieKendall 's help so far.

Comment: You can specify what fields you want in such a manner: "SELECT firstname, surname (or more, as long as it exists) FROM tablename"

If you want to select all fields from the table do "SELECT * FROM tablename"

Comment: Also, if you are retrieving more than 1 record, use a while loop; This should get you on the right track: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php